# Firebase notification MismatchSenderID

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Phonegap, Android (and later IOS). Firebase push notifications. This file php is in the server. not sure how to fix it. Been searching for hours and havent fixed this.
I have tried creating multiple new projects console.firebase.google.com, but nothing seems to work.
error:

```
{"multicast_id":4891894711706729720,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

<?php

define('SERVER_KEY', '(actualkeyIinserted');
$registrationIds = "";

(connected here, deleted line so I dont show info)

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    $result = "Connect failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_devices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["device"] . "<br>";
        $registrationIds = $row["device"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$mysqli->close();

if($registrationIds != ""){

    $msg = array
          (
        'body'  => 'Prato em encomenda',
        'title' => 'Alerta',
                'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
          );

    $fields = array
            (
                'to'        => $registrationIds,
                'notification'  => $msg
            );


    $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key=' . SERVER_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

    #Send Reponse To FireBase Server
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    #Echo Result Of FireBase Server
    echo $result;

}else{
    echo("No registration ID");
}
?>
```

Comment: The `MismatchSenderId` error is usually received if you are sending a message to a token associated with a sender (let's say sender1), but you are using a Server Key associated with a different sender (i.e. sender2). Make sure you are using the corresponding tokens and keys.

Comment: Firebase site, login, click on the gear -> settings, in that page you have the keys right? the SenderID is something like this 135148119184 and the key is a bunch of chars. The device I'm sending it to is inserted into the db via phonegap app (js), then this php gets the device key.
Am I wrong anywhere?